# Why this doble loop doesn't work as i expected?

Tags: list, python-2.7, for-loop, with-statement

I have two txt files, with 50000 and 25000 data to compare which data are in both files, but only the first line is compared and added to the list res1, (prints were just to get the idea of how it is working) when i run the code it prints the tuple (as expected), but then only prints the values in lineCue and avoid the second loop, the list result is only the first value taked by lineCue, and not all the values repeated in both files. when
i tried by another way the list content have 24808 repetitions... :(

```
contratos = 'C:\\CONTRATOS.txt'
cuentas = 'C:\\CUENTAS0.txt'

res1 = [[], []] # res1[0] -> ID, res1[1] -> NO ID
res2 = [] # res2 -> REPE
with open(cuentas, 'rb') as cue:
    with open(contratos, 'rb') as con:
        for lineCue in cue.xreadlines():
            print(lineCue)
            for lineCon in con.xreadlines():
                print(lineCue, lineCon)
                if lineCue == lineCon:
                    res1[0].append(lineCon)
print(res1[0])
```

output:

```
['O199924\r\n']
```

files:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33113171/CONTRATOS.txt
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33113171/CUENTAS0.txt

Comment: I would recommend creating a set if you are sure there isn't any repetition. You could store each file in a list and then compare such list with `in`. To avoid problems with the `\r\n\`I recommend you to use `.rstrip()` when comparing the lines, just in case it is not the same for both files

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration of the outer loop you read the whole file `con`. You need to read it from start each time. To do so, use `con.seek(0)` to go to the beginning of this file before entering the inner loop.